# Material UI ListItem Selected Styling in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using `material-ui` `ListItem` to show my nav bar items.

I wrote the following CSS code to show styling when each item selected.

```
<List>
  {routes.map(route => (
    <Link to={route.path} key={route.name} style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
      <ListItem button key={route.name} className={classes.listWrap}>
        <ListItemText primary={route.name} className={classes.listItemText} />
      </ListItem>
    </Link>
  ))}
</List>;
```

CSS

```css
listWrap: {
  "&:hover": {
    border: "1px solid #6c757d",
    color: "black"
  },
  textAlign: "center",
  "&:active": {
    background: "#6c757d",
    color: "black"
  }
}
```

**When I select one `ListItem` the styling doesn't work**

how can we fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `focus` instead of `active`.

```
listWrap: {
    "&:hover": {
      border: "1px solid #6c757d",
      color: "black"
    },
    textAlign: "center",
    "&:focus": {
      background: "#6c757d",
      color: "black"
    }
  }
```